# images from laravel storage cannot appear on hosting

Tags: php, laravel

**I have done php artisan storage:link and it works fine on my localhost, but it doesn't work when I have uploaded it to hosting**

this is my view

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/gallery/' . $data4->image) }}" class="img-responsive clients-img">
```

this is file filesystem.php

```
 'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Run same command on server also: "php artisan storage:link"

Comment: Thanks it solved

Answer (score 0):

Run the same command on the server also:

```
php artisan storage:link
```